# Is it possible in Vue JS to make several vue components reuse existing data structure with different data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2

I have two vue.js components, that are based on two same data structures, to that can be assigned different values, received from the server.

I want to autogenerate components (may be in "for" cycle) according to the data, received from server. This autogenerated components should have the same data structure but different values.

For example, now I have implemented dummy approach:

- I defined in template two vue.js components
- They are based on two different data structures
- Data structures are updated separately according to the server response.

How I want to be:

- I have something like "generator" for `n` vue.js components according to the number of series I have received from the server
- This components have the same vue data structures
- Data structures are updated centrally according to the server response.

**My current dummy solution:**
https://jsfiddle.net/t2j80bpn/7/

Comment: What's wrong with your fiddle, aside from hardcoding 2 charts instead of using `v-for` to render an arbitrary number of charts? And if you're going to be updating the data then the charts should have an ID so you can identify them.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, thans for reply! How it is possible to change data values depending on id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your "generator" is just a computed. Use `map` to transform your `data_from_server` into an array of objects for your graph. Or `visualize_data` could do the transformation into a real data item.

```js
Vue.use(HighchartsVue.default)


let data_from_server = [
  [1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 1, 9, 2],
  [11, 2, 6, 1, 9, 10, 1, 2]
]

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      dfs: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      return this.dfs.map((d, i) => ({
        id: i,
        chart: {
          type: 'spline'
        },
        title: `Chart ${i}`,
        series: [ {data: d}]
      }))
    }
  },
  methods: {
    visualise_data: function(event) {
      this.dfs = data_from_server;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/1ce7e656/dist/script-tag/highcharts-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="visualise_data">Change series</button>

  <highcharts v-for="opt in chartOptions" :options="opt" :key="opt.id"></highcharts>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was just I was looking for!